# Create time series of values based on 4 daily events, hourly factors and coefficients (Tidal speeds)

Tags: r, function, for-loop, dplyr, time-series

I have a dataset that shows daily high and low tidal events that looks like this:

```
#Create tidal times data frame
Date <- as_Date(c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03","2018-01-04", "2018-01-05", "2018-01-06", "2018-01-017")) #Which shows the daily date

first_tide <- hms::as_hms(c("01:14:00", "02:09:00", "03:21:00", "04:33:00", "05:27:00", "06:14:00", "07:09:00") #Which shows the time of the first tide

H_L1 <- c("High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low") #Which shows whether the first tide is a high or low tide event

second_tide <- hms::as_hms(c("06:37:00", "07:24:00", "08:13:00", "09:01:00", "09:57:00", "11:06:00", "12:09:00") #Which shows the time of the second tide

H_L2 <- c("Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High") #Which shows whether the second tide is a high or low tide event

third_tide <- hms::as_hms(c("13:28:00", "14:24:00", "15:13:00", "16:01:00", "16:57:00", "17:44:00", "18:39:00") #Which shows the time of the third tide

H_L3 <- c("High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low") #Which shows whether the third tide is a high or low tide event

fourth_tide <- hms::as_hms(c("19:01:00", "19:47:00", "20:13:00", "21:01:00", "21:57:00", "22:44:00", "NA") #Which shows the time of the fourth tide

H_L4 <- c("Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "NA") #Which shows whether the fourth tide is a high or low tide event

Coefficient <- c("very high ", "very high ", "high", "average", "average", "low", "low") #This shows whether the tides are spring (very high or high), neap (low) or average tide. These will be used for the corresponding spring/neap/average tide speeds later.

Ports_Tides <- data.frame(Date, first_tide, H_L1, second_tide, H_L2, third_tide, H_L3, fourth_tide, H_L4, Coefficient)
```

This data set shows the time of 4 tides per day (first_tide, second_tide, third_tide, and fourth_tide). The columns H_L1, H_L2, H_L3 and H_L4 show whether the first_tide, second_tide, third_tide or fourth_tide is a high or low tide event, respectively. In this analysis I only want to consider high tides.

I also have another data frame that shows the tidal speeds 5 hours before through to 6 hours after a high tide event (twice daily giving full 24 hours) for spring and neap tidal events.

```
#Create tidal speeds data frame
tidal_speeds <- data.frame(
  hours_before_high = c(-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  neap_speed = c(1.8, 1.6, 1.5, 1.2, 0.1, 1.2, 1.7, 1.9, 1.7, 1.2, 0.4, 0.8),
  spring_speed = c(3.7, 3.3, 2.9, 2.4, 0.3, 2.4, 3.4, 3.8, 3.4, 2.3, 0.8, 1.6)
)
```

I want to create a single time series for tidal speeds for the whole of the Ports_Tides days duration based off the tidal_speeds dataset for neap_speed, spring_speed and an average_speed (average of neap_speed and spring_speed) and the two daily high tidal events (high and low events determined by H_L1, H_L2, H_L3 and H_L4 for first_tide, second_tide, third_tide, and fourth_tide, respectively) and Coefficient in Ports_tides (very high and high = spring_speed, average = average_speed, and low = neap_speed). I am using R.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
library(dplyr)

# Create a function to calculate the appropriate tidal speed based on coefficient
calculate_tidal_speed <- function(coefficient, neap_speed, spring_speed) {
  if (coefficient %in% c("very high", "high")) {
    return(spring_speed)
  } else if (coefficient == "average") {
    return(calculate_average_speed(neap_speed, spring_speed))
  } else {
    return(neap_speed)
  }
}

# Create an empty data frame to store the time series
tidal_speed_time_series <- data.frame()

# Loop through each row in the Ports_Tides data frame
for (i in 1:nrow(Ports_Tides)) {
  date <- Ports_Tides$Date[i]
  
  # Determine the two high tide events for the day
  high_tides <- character(0)
  high_low_cols <- c("H_L1", "H_L2", "H_L3", "H_L4")
  for (col in high_low_cols) {
    if (!is.na(Ports_Tides[[col]][i]) && Ports_Tides[[col]][i] == "High") {
      high_tides <- append(high_tides, col)
      if (length(high_tides) == 2) {
        break
      }
    }
  }
  
  # Loop through the two high tide events
  for (high_tide_col in high_tides) {
    coefficient <- Ports_Tides$Coefficient[i]
    
    # Extract the name of the corresponding tidal event time column
    high_tide_time_col <- paste0(high_tide_col, "_tide")

#Extract the specific high tide time 
    high_tide_time <- Ports_Tides[[high_tide_time_col]][i]

#Find the index of the correct hour in the tidal_speeds data frame
idx <- match(high_tide_time, tidal_speeds$hours_before_high)
    neap_speed <- tidal_speeds$neap_speed[idx]
    spring_speed <- tidal_speeds$spring_speed[idx]
    
    tidal_speed <- calculate_tidal_speed(coefficient, neap_speed, spring_speed)
    
    tidal_speed_time_series <- rbind(tidal_speed_time_series,
                                     data.frame(Date = date,
                                                Time = high_tide_time,
                                                Tidal_Speed = tidal_speed))
  }
}

# Print the resulting time series
print(tidal_speed_time_series)
```

Not sure whether I am over complicating this (sure someone knows of an easier way to do this!) but I am receiving the error:

Error in data.frame(Date = date, Time = high_tide_time, Tidal_speed = tidal_speed)

Arguments imply differing number or rows : 1,0

If anyone could help I would be extremely grateful! It should be replicable but if not let me know and I will supply more data. My dataset is for a whole year so maybe there is an issue there, not sure.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ellis! A couple of things: 1. this is quite complicated for a StackOverflow question. I would try to simplify things if you can. 2. while I've been able to make sense of part 1, the Ports_Tides dataset, the rest of it is a bit hard to follow. Are you trying to create one time series, or hundred? It sounds a lot like a hundred haha